# Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "cellClass". Expected String with value "[object Object]", got Object

Tags: vue.js, buefy

I'm trying to conditionally apply a CSS class to a row (all `b-table-column`) in a `b-table`, like this:

```html
<b-table-column class="is-unselectable" 
    :cell-class="{ 'has-pointer-cursor': props.row.url != null }" 
    field="version" label="Name" :custom-sort="sortName" sortable>

    <!-- Content -->

</b-table-column>
```

The class `has-pointer-cursor` exists in the style part of that `vue` page/component.

I'm getting this error/warning in the console:

> [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "cellClass". 
>          Expected String with value "[object Object]", got Object
>
> ```
> found in
>
> ---> <BTableColumn>
>        <BTable>
>          <MyPage> at src/views/MyPage.vue
>            <App> at src/App.vue
>              <Root>
> ```

But somehow, it's working as expected (not taking into consideration the error message)!

What's happening and how it still works? Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `b-table-column` component expects a string value for the `cell-class` prop but you are passing it an object.

[image]

Try this instead

```html
<b-table-column :cell-class="props.row.url ? 'has-pointer-cursor' : ''" ...>
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked (the error messages are gone), but do you know why the it was working before (but with error messages)? Isn't the prop `class` expecting a `String` type too?

Comment: No, Vue is able to handle `class` bindings in various ways, including an object. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html. How the Buefy component handles its `cell-class` prop is up to them. They've chosen to set it as a string type